# How to enable a function after another function has timed out

Tags: jquery

I've been learning jQuery, and I'm trying to create a simple game to test what I've learned so far. Here's the game:

A grid of 100 green dots. You click *any* of the dots to turn 10 of the dots blue (at random). Three seconds later the ten blue dots revert back to green. Now you have to click all of the green dots that *were* blue to turn them blue again. It's a simple memory game.

So far I've got the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#greengrid').one('click', function() {
    $('.greentoblue').css('background-color', 'blue');
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.greentoblue').css('background-color','green');
        }, 3000);   
}); });
```

This turns 10 of the blue dots green when you click *any* dot, then disables the code so that you can't reveal all the blue dots simultaneously again.

Now I want you to be able to turn the "secret" blue dots blue again by clicking each one individually. I don't know how to do this. Anyone? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: That game seems SUPER hard.

Comment: @pmandell what a comment hahaha

Comment: So, is the question "How can I make it wait x seconds?" or "How can I 'disable' a function?" or both?

Comment: @Yatrix The question seems to be pretty clear, at least to me.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Good for you.

Comment: @Yatrix That first click inside `<div id="#greengrid"></div>` reveals all the blue dot for three seconds. Now I want you to be able to click where you remember the blue dots being to turn them blue again (one by one). The overall challenge (for me) is getting this to work only _after_ that first click that revealed all the blue dots for three seconds.

Comment: what is every dot? a div with some class? See my answer below if it helps.. It will not work as it is becuase I dont know what is every dot

Comment: @rahulmaindargi, all of the dots are in `<div id="#greengrid"></div>` and every dot has the class `green`, and ten of the dots also have the class `greentoblue` which are the ones that turn blue on that first click.

Answer (score 1):

Just bind a one time `click` event handler to those elements at the same time that you make them green again:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#greengrid').one('click', function () {
        $('.greentoblue').css('background-color', 'blue');
        setTimeout(function () {
          $('.greentoblue').css('background-color', 'green').one('click', function(e) {
            $(this).css('background-color', 'blue'); // this is the element clicked on
          });
        }, 3000);
    });
});
```

The above is a very basic example, but there's an issue with it: the "non-blue" dots won't react to clicks at all, so they could just randomly click until they find them. Instead you'd probably want to bind a click event handler to **all** dots, and then check if they should turn blue (check the presence of the `greentoblue` class using `.hasClass()`).

You could also possibly add a counter to track the number of guesses (so you can limit them), and also check if all the blue dots have been found so you have a winning condition. That's slightly more involved, but the basic principle is the same: you bind a one-time click event handler to all elements inside of the function passed to `setTimeout()`.

Something like this instead:

```
$(selector for dots).one('click', function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.hasClass('greentoblue')) {
        $this.css('background-color', 'blue');
    }
    else {
        $this.css('background-color', 'red');
    }
});
```

Comment: That worked, thanks! But what is the "e" in `function(e)` doing? And if I want _non_  `.greentoblue` dots to turn red when you click them (_after_ that initial click), how would I do that?

Comment: @JordanM. The `e` is a parameter, which will refer to the jQuery normalised event passed to the handler function. Feel free to either take it out or ignore it. I generally always specify it as a habit, so that I have it available if I need to, for example, prevent the default action associated with that event (e.g. not following a link that's clicked on).

Comment: @JordanM. (cont) I also had a thought related to that, and edited a note into my answer about it. Without knowing the exact HTML of the page I can't tell you the exact code, but the basic principle would be binding an event handler to *all* of the dots, and deciding whether or not it should turn blue or red inside of that.

Comment: Anthony, thanks very much for your answers. My simple game isn't as simple as I'd hoped, it seems. That said, I'm going to take a stab at what you said ("bind a click event handler to all dots, and then check if they should turn blue").

Comment: Anthony, I'm trying the following code but it's not working. There's an error in the syntax that I'm not spotting.

`$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#greengrid').one('click', function () {
        $('.greentoblue').css('background-color', 'blue');
        setTimeout(function () {
   $('.green').one('click', function(e) {
      var $this = $(this);
      if($this.hasClass('greentoblue')) {
         $this.css('background-color', 'blue');
       }
      else {
         $this.css('background-color', 'red');
    }
});
    });`

Comment: @JordanM. You seem to be missing two sets of closing brackets (`})` in that comment, not sure if that's the issue with your actual code too.

Answer (score 0):

Add a CSS class to mark which dots were previously blue. When the user clicks again, check if it has that class `if($(this).hasClass('was-blue')) {....}`

```
 $('.greentoblue').css('background-color','green').addClass('was-blue');
```

Comment: Why would you add a class? The `greentoblue` class seems to already track which ones are being switched.

Comment: But now I can win by running `$(".was-blue").click()`

Comment: @AnthonyGrist yea you might be right. I don't think the OP's code is complete. How were the greentoblue originally assigned to the dots?

Comment: @MathewFoscarini I don't know, but also don't think it matters how they got there, only that we can assume they are there when the first click event handler function is executed. Could be randomly assigned using a server-side language or via another JavaScript function.

Comment: The `greentoblue` class designates the "secretly" blue dots. That first click inside `<div id="#greengrid"></div>` reveals all the blue dot for three seconds. Now I want you to be able to click where you remember the blue dots being to turn them blue again. So I'm confused about the need to add another class (`was-blue`). The overall challenge (for me) is getting this to work only _after_ that first click to reveal all the blue dots for three seconds.

Answer (score 0):

If I undersand your question correctly.you are able to Convert 10 Green dots to blue.. and then back to Green

now what you want is when user click on that "Secret" green dot again. it should turn Blue else alert wrong click and reset game .. am i right?

If so follwoing should help you.. let me know if you need any clarification...

Also a jsfiddle for your code will be helpful to help you

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var quizStarted=false;
     $('#greengrid').on('click', function() {
        if(quizStarted)
             return;
        quizStarted=true;
        $('.greentoblue').css('background-color', 'blue');
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.greentoblue').css('background-color','green');
            $('.greentoblue').addClass("wasBlue");
        }, 3000);   
        
     });
  
     $('.green').click(function(){

        if(!quizStarted)
            return;
        if($(this).hasClass("wasBlue")){
          $(this).css('background-color', 'blue');
          /* Get count of Selected Blue dots*/
          var selectedBlueDots=$('#greengrid').filter(function() {
                var match = 'blue'; // match background-color: blue
             /*
                  true = keep this element in our wrapped set
                 false = remove this element from our wrapped set
                                                     */
               return ( $(this).css('background-color') == match );

            }).size();
            if(selectedBlueDots== 10){
               alert("You won");
               $(".wasBlue").css('background-color', 'green');
               $(".wasBlue").removeClass("wasBlue");
               quizStarted=false;
            }
        }else{ 
           alert("You Forgot");
            $(".wasBlue").css('background-color', 'green');
            $("not(.wasBlue)").css('background-color', 'red');                
            $(".wasBlue").removeClass("wasBlue");
            
            quizStarted=false;
        }

     });
 });
```

Just for fun I tried same thing...
And have **[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/avURR/)**

Comment: Rahul, thanks for your answer. This exceeds my jQuery knowledge at the moment, the `if` statements in particular, so I'm going to have to go learn some more before I can make sense of your code.

Comment: Rahul, thanks! I have to step away from the computer for a bit but will take a look at the code asap.